# how can i write an event for segment controller?

Tags: iphone

i want to write an event for the segment controller.By clicking First Tab i want to perform some calculation and by clicking Second Tab i want to perform some different operation.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an IBAction

```
-(IBAction)segCtrlValueChanged:(UISegmentControl*)segCtrl;
```

and then link the "Value Changed" event to this action in Interface Builder, *or* programmatically, call

```
[segmentationControl addTarget:foo action:@selector(segCtrlValueChanged:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

If the IBAction, check `segCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex` to see which item is active.